# Python Splitting A String to make several keys for a dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, key

so I am trying to write a function that will read a text file, extract the information it needs from a line of text, and then assign that information to a key in a python dictionary. However here is a problem i have.

```
def read_star_names(filename):
"""
Given the name of a file containing a star catalog in CSV format, produces a dictionary 
where the keys are the names of the stars and the values are Henry Draper numbers as integers.

If a star has more than one name, each name will appear as a key 
in the dictionary. If a star does not have a name it will not be 
represented in this dictionary.

example return: {456: 'BETA', 123: 'ALPHA', 789: 'GAMMA;LITTLE STAR'}
"""
result_name = {}
starfile = open(filename, 'r')
for dataline in starfile:
    items = dataline.strip().split(',')
    draper = int(items[3])
    name = str(items[6])
    result_name[name] = draper
starfile.close()
return result_name
```

This is attempting to read this:

0.35,0.45,0,123,2.01,100,ALPHA

-0.15,0.25,0,456,3.2,101,BETA

0.25,-0.1,0,789,4.3,102,GAMMA;LITTLE STAR

The problem I am having is that what it returns is this:
{'ALPHA': 123, 'GAMMA;LITTLE STAR': 789, 'BETA': 456}

I want the GAMMA and the LITTLE STAR, to be seperate keys, but still refer to the same number, 789.

How should I proceed? 
I tried splitting the line of text at the semicolon but then that added indexes and I had a hard time managing them.

Thanks.

Comment: The description of the method in the comment doesn't match what you've described in the question

Comment: I got it to work ! I was also naming name as name = str(items[6]) which was adding the original problem value to the dictionary !

Answer (score 0):

You already have isolated the part that contains all the names, all you need to do is separate the names and make separate keys for each of them, as so

```
 for i in name.split(";"):
        result_name[i] = draper
```